# rounding up columns of values

Tags: c#

I start with figures in line 1 for columns A nd B, (see below) 890 and 450 and both are divided by 1.2 to get a net figure (line 2), the results of which are then split over two types (say salesA and salesB)
How can I ensure that the sum of salesA + salesB will always be equal to the values shown on line 2 which in turn will be equal to values on line 1 when multiplied by 20%. 
As you can see, column B is out by 0.02

Example

```
  column A        column B
  890.00 /1.2     450.00 /1.2
  741.67          375.00
  333.33 salesA   208.35 salesA
  408.34 salesB   166.67 salesB

  741.67          375.02   sum of salesA + sales B
```

Values on line 2 multiplied by 20% should be equal to values on line 1
How can this be achieved ? I am aware of Math.Round. 
Have tried inserting it everywhere but it doesn’t work
The division operator is inside a select statement

Comment: The issue is that 375.02 * 1.2 = 450.02 not 450.00 how did you get 450.00? What data type are you using to store these values?

Comment: 450 is the starting figure

Comment: the code inside an select statement is simply [salesA]/1.2.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something like this when splitting:

```
total = 741.67
a = round(f(total), 2)
b = round(g(total), 2)
```

where f() and g() are the calculations used to split. Instead do this:

```
total = 741.67
a = round(f(total), 2)
b = total - a;
```

Now `a + b` are always equal to `total`.

However, you will never be able to get the starting value again when multiplying with `1.2` because of the rounding.

Comment: That's the point, how to get it so it will always be equal to the starting figure

Comment: or perhaps it is simply not possible ?

Comment: When rounding, information gets lost unavoidably. Unless you store the rounding error somewhere, you can not get the starting figure again!